# Pandas Groupby integer with margin of error

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with two integer columns that represent the start and end of a string of text. I'd like to group my rows by length of text (end - start), but with a margin of error of +- 5 characters so that something like this would happen:

```
 start    end
 0        251
 1        250
 2        250

 0        500
 1        500
 0        499
```

How would I achieve something like this?
Here is the code I am using right now

```
d = {'text': ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff"], 
    'start': [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0], 
    'end': [250, 500, 501, 251, 249, 499]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = df.groupby(['start', 'end'])
```

Comment: include your df

Comment: Here, I added one.

Comment: A problem rises. What if there is a string with length 244, another with 248, another with 250. How do you want to group them? ie `[244,248],[250]` or `[244], [248, 250]` or `[244,248, 250]` Note that the third grouping cannot work because 244 is 6 away from 250, and the second cannot work because 244 is 4 away from 248 yet in different groups, similar to the first one ie 248 is 2 away from 250 yet in different groups. So how do you want to tackle this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What if I looked at intervals instead? 240-245 is one interval, 245-250 is another, 250-255 is another, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by rounding the length of my text.

```
df['rounded_length'] = (df['end'] - df['start']).round(-1)

df = df.groupby('rounded_length')
```

All my values become multiples of 10, and I can group them this way.